# Regular expression: Replace everything before first occurence

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regular expression that I'm using to remove the `dev.` part of my URL.

```
String domain = "dev.mydomain.com";
System.out.println(domain.replaceAll(".*\\.(?=.*\\.)", ""));
```

Outputs: `mydomain.com` but this is giving me issues when the domains are in the vein of `dev.mydomain.com.pe` or `dev.mydomain.com.uk` in those cases I am getting only the `.com.pe` and `.com.uk` parts.

Is there a modifier I can use on my regex to make sure it only takes what is before the first `.` (dot included)?

Desired output:

`dev.mydomain.com` -> `mydomain.com`

`stage.mydomain.com.pe` -> `mydomain.com.pe`

`test.mydomain.com.uk` -> `mydomain.com.uk`

Comment: Would `^[^.]*\\.` work? i.e. "at the start of the string, any number of characters that aren't `.`, ending with the first occurrence of `.`". This removes the need for look-ahead.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy that absolutely works! But I just noticed an edge case, when in production the expression break because there is no `dev.`, the old expression did work for a plain `mydomain.com` the new one in this case would return a `.com`.

So perhaps `^[^.]*\\.(?=.*\\.)` ?

Comment: In that case you could also use `^[^.]*\.(?=[^.]+\.)` or be specific about what to match `^(?:dev|stage|test)\.`

Comment: Is a regex necessary?  Why not use `domain.substring(domain.indexOf('.') + 1)`?

Comment: @VGR we are using AEM, thus Java. I did move the logic to a clientlib and used that exact solution in the end though, funny you would suggest that haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[^.]+\.(?=.*\.)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pNknvT/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B%5E.%5D%2B%5C.(%3F%3D.*%5C.)):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^.]+` - 1 or more chars other than dots
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?=.*\.)` - followed with any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a `.`.

Java usage example:

```
String result = domain.replaceFirst("^[^.]+\\.(?=.*\\.)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Following regex will work for you. It will find first part (if exists), captures rest of the string as 2nd matching group and replaces the string with 2nd matching group. `.*?` is non-greedy search that will match until it sees first dot character.

`(.*?\.)?(.*\..*)`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L2Dhuu/1/)

**sample code:**

```
String domain = "dev.mydomain.com";
System.out.println(domain.replaceAll("(.*?\\.)?(.*\\..*)", "$2"));

domain = "stage.mydomain.com.pe";
System.out.println(domain.replaceAll("(.*?\\.)?(.*\\..*)", "$2"));

domain = "test.mydomain.com.uk";
System.out.println(domain.replaceAll("(.*?\\.)?(.*\\..*)", "$2"));

domain = "mydomain.com";
System.out.println(domain.replaceAll("(.*?\\.)?(.*\\..*)", "$2"));
```

**output:**

```
mydomain.com
mydomain.com.pe
mydomain.com.uk
mydomain.com
```

Comment: This works but it doesn't solve the original case, in which the domain is `mydomin.com.uk` in that case it would still return `.com.uk` only.

Comment: is `mydomain` constant name? or it can change also?!

Comment: In this case, it is constant

Comment: then you can use it in the regex, like `(.*?\.)?(mydomain\..*)`, right?
 https://regex101.com/r/L2Dhuu/2